# Position of a puzzle piece in Flash Jigsaw puzzle

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3, logic

I have a 4*4 grid. I have 16 MovieClips  scattered around the grid. Each MovieClip is 40*40 and they are draggable. The user can drag and drop the MovieClips into the grid. Each clip has a correct position. For example for

clip 0  : x=0 , y=0

clip 1  : x=40, y=0

clip 2  : x=120 , y=0

clip 3  : x=160 , y=0

clip 15 : x=160 , y=160

The game finishes when all the clips are in correct position. So its easy to check for game over. Use a loop and ENTER_FRAME to monitor the positions of all clips.

There is a small problem I cannot solve. When the user drags a clip it will snap to position in the grid whether it is correct or not. The snappable positions will be multiples of 40 in this case. It is possible for two clips to snapped to a location and this has to be avoided. If I have put a clip at (40,120) I should not be able drop another MovieClip there. In effect I should be able to get some indication telling me that this position is occupied.

Using the indication I will make the MovieClip return to original position.

How can this can be achieved. The registration points of MovieClips are topleft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carry an object with information about the occupation of the 16 fields. If a clip is present, set the appropriate property to true. Alternative: A nifty solution is to simply use an int var and a binary sum:

```
1 = first field
2 = second field
4 = third field
8 = ...
```

If the first three positions are occupied, your sum will be `1 + 2 + 4 = 7`.

You test if a field is occupied like this:

```
if ((SUM & testFieldNumber) == testFieldNumber) THEN occupied
```

At the time the user releases the mouse you need to calculate the position the clip will snap into. Check if the field is occupied using your object or the binary sum thing. If so, reset the position of the clip to its former state. If the field is still free, you add the field to your object or the binaray sum:

```
SUM += fieldNumber
```

If a clip leaves its field:

```
SUM -= fieldNumber
```

Summary:

- Store always the last valid position of each of your clips
- Store the occupation of the fields (object or binary sum)
- Calculate the possible clip position (field) when the user releases the mouse
- If field is free: Move clip there, store field occupation (in object or bin sum). Store the new position of the clip as last valid position.
- If field is occupied: Move clip to its former position
- When clip leaves its former position update the field occupation list (object or bin sum)

Comment: I prefer to go with object method. I am a bit rusty about Logical AND OR etc. But I think I have got the basic idea. Could you give me some good links to whether such kind of code using the  'int var and  binary sum'. If you have any sample code please send. I would like to study that method for the future.  bobbyfrancisjoseph@gmail.com

Comment: To use binary sums, you really don't need to understand the concepts of bit operators. I even would have to look at the docs to explain them. You basically only need to now that you can have a single number and are able to check if the number contains a certain value. To do so the values need to be powers of 2. Its the same as with the unix file permissions.